# How to remove a commit from Sourcetree github project

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I just renamed a field in my project that later I understood that caused my app to crash now. I want to reverse my commit to an earlier commit and edit and write my code from there. Now, the problem is when I reset the branch to that commit and I want to make new pushes, it tells me that I have to pull first because the branch is behind. I can't push. I am working on Sourcetree in Windows. Any idea how to fix that?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y08cb.jpg
I added the image to better understand here. I want to reset to `df`.

[image: before changed naming]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove a commit on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448919/how-can-i-remove-a-commit-on-github)

Comment: nope because i wanted to know it in source tree app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the commits after `df`, you can do an hard reset in SourceTree to `df` commit.

Right-click on `df`, and select "reset current branch to this commit".
Note that this will [implies to force push](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43243688/6309), which is OK if you are the only one working on that project.

Answer (score 1):

In SourceTree, select the last "good" commit (i.e. one older than the one you want to delete). Then call `Repository` -> `Interactive Rebase...`. You can change the complete revision history here. When done, push and make sure to check the "Force Push" checkbox at the bottom of the dialog.

If the checkbox is grayed out, you need to enable it first: open `Tools` -> `Options`, tab `Git`. Check "Enable Force Push".